# Less than equal to (<=) relation as morphism between natural numbers (objects)

Tags: category-theory

How can I prove that "less than equal to" relation is valid morphism between natural numbers in category theory i.e it composes associatively.

Answer (score 0):

Natural numbers are totally ordered with regards to $ \leq $.  Due to this $ \leq $ is transitive for all triples of natural numbers.  That is $ a \leq b \land b \leq c \implies a \leq c $.  Composition flows from this.